# Scale Iframe tag to Bigger Size

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a problem with my iframe! How can I make the content of the iframe fill the screen?

Thank you in advance.

### Photos:

**Current Output:**
[image: Current Output]

**Wanted Output**
[image: Wanted Output]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://octopi/webcam/?action=stream" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden">
            Your browser doesn't support iframes
        </iframe>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qL-ry_tz6V0" style="width:100%; height:100vh; overflow:hidden">
            Your browser doesn't support iframes
        </iframe>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

You can use this: height:100vh

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Does your problem persist when you add "height:100vh"? Also, please remove the "position:absolute" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. First set `margin: 0; padding: 0;` for all using `*{}` universal selector so that everything fits to screen. **Note: It's a reset CSS code so it might effect other designs if not handled carefully**
2. Then set `width:100%; height:100vh; overflow:hidden` for iframe. *Here `vh` means view height*
3. Set `border: 0 solid transparent;` to iframe to remove border. **Note: if you want to keep border then subtract the thickness of borders from width and hight using `calc()` function of CSS**

Then your iframe will fit to screen!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qL-ry_tz6V0">
            Your browser doesn't support iframes
        </iframe>
    </div>
    
    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      iframe{
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        overflow:hidden;
        border: 0 solid transparent;
      }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this style code for iframe:

```css
iframe{
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
```